# Show Git version in R Code

Tags: r, git, rstudio, knitr

I am using Git as a version control (currently the centralised workflow, but I would like to move to feature branch or gitflow workflow).  I use RStudio/Knitr to compile PDF documents and would like to know how I can automatically include the current Git version in the PDF - if that works?  That way, when somebody comes back to me with a document I have given them, I know how to return to that point in the code. Any suggestions will be much appreciated, thanks - Marie.

Edit: Keywords is what I had in mind, although according to this post (gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0610/28891.html) not recommended. Are there any recommendations on helper scripts? –  user1420372 just now

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, but `git rev-parse --short HEAD` will get you the shortened SHA1 hash of the last commit, which you can then check out. I believe doing `system("git rev-parse --short HEAD", intern = TRUE)` from R should do the trick.

Comment: @WanderNauta you should make that an answer.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I don't have R/RStudio/Knitr so I have no way to test my outrageous claims - if you do, and it does indeed work, feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doing this only for presenting a soup-to-nuts example. It was @Wander Nauta's idea (from comments on the question).

Here's a tiny knitr doc:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
print(system("git rev-parse --short HEAD", intern = TRUE))
```
````

that I have in a freshly created local git repo.

When I knit to PDF I get this:

[image]

so you should be able to use this for watermarking the git commit it was generated from.

Alternately, if you're good with adding another package dependency to your projects, you can use the `git2r` package:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(git2r)

repo <- repository(".")
print(head(repo))
```
````

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: what about include a `system("git --version")` ?

Comment: well, that gives the version of the actual `git` executable. not sure how helpful that is.

Answer (score 6):

The suggestion to use the git2r package is a really good one. With a few more functions, you can isolate the actual SHA. You can also repurpose, e.g., the Author field to get the SHA in the document header, if that is of interest.

Here's the R Markdown document:

````
---
title: "Show Git version in R Code"
output: html_document
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
author: "SHA: `r git2r::branch_target(git2r::head(git2r::repository(getwd())))`"
---

You could also put the SHA elsewhere, like in a concluding chunk along with session info.

```{r collapse = TRUE}
git2r::branch_target(git2r::head(git2r::repository(getwd())))
## ADD devtools::session_info() or sessionInfo() ??
```
````

Which gives

[image]

Comment: See also [`devtools:::git_repo_sha1()`](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/f0d1c7ed3d7f30d559b62eb0060135589824c687/R/git.R#L6-L17) if you need it to work for tags or detached heads.

Comment: Is there a way to get this answer to work when the working directory is at `my_repo/my_subdir` instead of in `my_repo`?

Comment: It's now `r git2r::branch_target(git2r::repository_head(getwd()))` because `head.git_repository()` is deprecated since https://github.com/ropensci/git2r/commit/4602da9c22b7afeed323f081bf7c53064bb6a09e#diff-61e79092175c782697e16cc58b012c02